# Sublime text: How to get the file name of the current view

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, filenames, delete-file

I'm trying to write a tiny plugin to delete the current file and close the active view.
For some reason self.view.file_name() always returns None.

I'm new to Python and I've no idea why it doesn't work like this. According to the [API Reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View) file_name() returns the file name of the current view.

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, send2trash

class DeleteCurrentFileCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):        
        f = self.view.file_name()
        if (f is None):
            return

        send2trash.send2trash(f)
        self.view.window().run_command('close')
```

Output of dir(self.view):

> ['**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**doc**', '**format**', '**getattribute**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**len**', '**module**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', 'add_regions', 'begin_edit', 'buffer_id', 'classify', 'command_history', 'em_width', 'encoding', 'end_edit', 'erase', 'erase_regions', 'erase_status', 'extract_completions', 'extract_scope', 'file_name', 'find', 'find_all', 'find_all_results', 'find_by_selector', 'fold', 'folded_regions', 'full_line', 'get_regions', 'get_status', 'get_symbols', 'has_non_empty_selection_region', 'id', 'indentation_level', 'indented_region', 'insert', 'is_dirty', 'is_folded', 'is_loading', 'is_read_only', 'is_scratch', 'layout_extent', 'layout_to_text', 'line', 'line_endings', 'line_height', 'lines', 'match_selector', 'meta_info', 'name', 'replace', 'retarget', 'rowcol', 'run_command', 'scope_name', 'score_selector', 'sel', 'set_encoding', 'set_line_endings', 'set_name', 'set_read_only', 'set_scratch', 'set_status', 'set_syntax_file', 'set_viewport_position', 'settings', 'show', 'show_at_center', 'size', 'split_by_newlines', 'substr', 'syntax_name', 'text_point', 'text_to_layout', 'unfold', 'viewport_extent', 'viewport_position', 'visible_region', 'window', 'word']

Comment: Any error msgs in the console?

Comment: No. The check for `(f is None)` is always true and therefore it returns before it reaches `send2trash()`. Without checking the `send2trash()` call fails.
When I execute `view.file_name()` in the console it returns the correct path.

Comment: what is the output of print dir(self.view) ?

Comment: Added the output to the question.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem, at last if you "print self.view.file_name()" you actually see the file name? If yes probably the problem is with the send2trash

Comment: Nope, I already tried that and it prints `None`, too.
Thats why I'm asking here. It doesn't make any sense to me because there is so little code and it should work like that :/

Comment: Yes I agree, I have tested it a bit here and the only way I get a Null is when the file is not saved.

Comment: Weird. The files I've been testing with are all saved. I tried several different files at different places, re-opened them, restarted ST2 but it never worked here.
I even downloaded the portable version of ST2 to check if theres something wrong with my installation and got the same result...

Comment: Are you using the command in a buffer that actually exists on disk?

Comment: Yes. All files I tested that with have been saved before executing my command.

Comment: I just tested this and it works! How are you calling the command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Plugins page of the unofficial documentation](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html?highlight=ApplicationCommand#conventions-for-command-names), Sublime Text normalises command names in the following way:

1. Strip off the "Command" suffix
2. Separate camel cased phrases with underscores

Thus, DeleteCurrentFileCommand should be called in the following way:
   `view.run_command("delete_current_file")`

With this command, I was able to run your plugin exactly as listed above in the Python console.

However, if I tried running `view.run_command("DeleteCurrentFile")`, then the console would display a blank line. This may have led to the idea that self.view.file_name() was returning None.

Comment: Oh man I feel stupid now. I tried to run the command on the window object like this `window.run_command('delete_current_file')` which is obviously wrong. It works when I call `view.run_command()`. Thanks!